# Possible work around "Invalid Octal Digit" in char when typing Alt Keys

Tags: c++, key, alt, octal

I am writing a program that executes the quadratic formula. My only problem is the actual formatting of the program. The alt keys that allow me to type the plus-minus sign and square root symbol are giving me some problems.

The problem exists within

```
cout<< 0-b << char(241) << char(251) << char(0178);
```

The last char to type the squared symbol (²) reports the invalid octal digit error. Is there a way around this or will i have to satisfy by simply writing " x^2 " ?

Comment: 8 is not a valid digit in octal.

Comment: I would stick to `x^2`. The error is from `char(0178)`. Literals starting with 0 are octal literals.

Answer (score 1):

You should just remove the leading `0` from `0178`. A leading zero on a numeric constant is automatically treated as octal and `8` is not a valid octal digit.

In addition, the [superscript-2 character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm) you're referring to is *decimal* 178, `U+00B2`. Another way would be to just use `'\xb2'` in your code.

Of course, you also have to be certain that whatever is interpreting that output stream knows about the Unicode characters that you're trying to output. This probably depends on your terminal program or console. If it doesn't, you may have to resort to hacks like `(x^2)` or, even worse, monstrosities like:

```
      3     2
    3x  - 7x  + 42x - 1
y = -------------------
            12
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although i wasn't quite sure how to implement it. For example "char("\u00B2")" didn't render the correct symbol (Im using Visual Studio 2012 Express for my IDE by the way). While "char(253)"gives me the correct formatting. Thank you very much though because without this response i would have known that the symbol i was trying to find was subscript 2 and i wouldn't have stumbled upon the correct code. EDIT: Lol holy crap that monstrosities looks hilarious. I never thought i would find humor in the quadratic equation.